# Send JSONP data to Google Apps script from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, jsonp

I am trying to send data to a google app script, to create and insert data into a sheet. What I would like to happen is that the person using the page, will be the one asked to authorize the app (only allowed within the organization). So when authorized, the javascript on the page will send data via jsonp to an app script, which will process and generate a sheet, and then save it to the users drive, and show them the link (or open it up in a new tab).

But when I try this I am running into issues. Here is javascript in my app (not in googles html, my own app).

```
var foo = function(data) {
    console.log('foo')
    console.log(data)
}

var url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/viedu.org/s/AKfycbzF6g9dAC5DI7Qtl0VD3QeYGsDbo43XxuVtoEYSHEA5_4yibYFN/exec"
console.log(url)

var data = {
    "foo": "bar"
}

$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    // The name of the callback parameter
    jsonp: "callback",
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "json",
    jsonpCallback: foo,
    "data": data
})
.done(function(response) {
  console.log('success')
  console.log(response)
})
.fail(function(response) {
  console.log('fail')
  console.log(response)
})
```

and my app script:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var cb = e.parameter.callback;
  var data = JSON.stringify({"data":"bar"});
  var outputStr = cb + "(" + data + ")";

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(outputStr)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

}
```

and my response in chrome console:

```
fail
script.html:39 Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

the response from the app script seems to be coming back as undefined. but im not sure why. If I try almost anything else in the jquery, I get errors stating it is trying to parse html/text and is invalid javascript. But I don't see what has to change in the app script as it looks fairly straight forward.

Comment: It is worth checking to make sure that your web-app has Who can access set to Anyone, even anonymous.

Comment: Why would we set it to anonymous if we want to restrict access to our organization? Since I want the user triggering the script to he authorized so the sheet saves in their drive account.

Comment: But if your app script has restricted access, you can only access it if you pass the authentication along with your ajax call. AFAIK, there's no oAuth scope specific for Apps Script, but full Google Drive access might work.

Comment: So your app is hosted somewhere and from there you want to call apps script? is that correct? If you want to access the user's Drive you will have them to authenticate with OAuth (yes even in apps script) If you just call Drive service in apps script, it will be your own because is taking the owner of the script.  If you already have your webapp, you can authenticate the users and access their Drive, here is the documentation. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en   and here is an example: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(outputStr).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

with this:

```
var params = JSON.stringify(getr);
return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);
```